# php-cs-fixer - disable/modify no_superfluous_phpdoc_tags rule

Tags: configuration, php-cs-fixer

I want to disable `no_superfluous_phpdoc_tags` rule.

```
/**
 * Refund a list of payments.
 *
 * @param float  $amount
 * @param array  $charges
 *
 * @throws PaymentException
 *
 * @return boolean
 *
 */
```

With the rule defaults it turns the above into this.

```
/**
 * Refund a list of payments.
 *
 * @throws PaymentException
 *
 */
```

I tried this:

```
./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix -vvv --rules='{"no_superfluous_phpdoc_tags": {"allow_unused_params": "true"}}'
```

But it doesn't affect the result (still removes the params). What can I do to not remove these params?

Answer (score 3):

In the **php_cs.dist** file:

```
'no_superfluous_phpdoc_tags' => false,
```

or in the **console**:

```
vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix .php_cs.dist --rules='{"no_superfluous_phpdoc_tags": false}'
```